# python unicast and multicast socket in one

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to listen for UDP unicast and Multicast messages on the same port - only 1 socket to open is allowable. Is any way to do this? I hope so since capture tools like wireshark can do so. I can create listen servers separately for unicast and multicast but need to listen for those packets at once.

Comment: you can set the socket with `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` If you want to have more sockets on one port.

Comment: Binding on the same port causes exception despite using those options. Can you provide me any working code part as example?